# Ploting classifiers' performance results for different datasets

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization

I have five different data sets, and I applied five classifiers.
I have also five performance evaluation metrics: precision, recall, F-measure, Accuracy, and AU-ROC.
Is there any good plot that I can use to compare these results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use ROC plots alot and I like to plot the different classifiers ROC plots on the same graph, like so:

[image: Imgur]

(Note x-axis is false positive rate & y-axis are true positive rate)